# How do you create a passcode entry in the python shell?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, passwords

How do you create a modified `input()` function so that when you type anything in, something different than what you typed in appears in the shell?

Example output:

```
>>> input('in>')
in> ***********
hello world
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the show= example and explanation at effbot http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Tk for this, however with the root withdrawed. Bind the root to detect any key press, and when detected, record the key press but print out a `'*'`

For a basic single-use password, this is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

cp = ''
root = Tk()

def process(event):
    global cp
    key = event.keysym
    if key == 'Return':
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        print(cp)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        if len(key) == 1:
            cp += key
            sys.stdout.write('*')


root.bind('<Key>', process)

root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

If you will call this from another program or will use this multiple times, 
using a shared file and using subprocesses might help.